# Predict time series with Statsmodels VAR and encountering ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm trying to forecast future values from my monthly dataset (the data is summarized as first day of a month, 12 times a year) and I'm encountering:

**ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.**

I've tried to run around Google and StackO but failed to get a relevant thread and a good enough solution.

This is head(13) of my dataframe:

```
            Occupancy rate  Average Price     RevPAR
Date                                                
2013-01-01        0.579026     105.289497  60.965332
2013-02-01        0.637415     109.396682  69.731070
2013-03-01        0.714847     117.840534  84.237901
2013-04-01        0.716446     122.765139  87.954593
2013-05-01        0.771097     105.461387  81.320985
2013-06-01        0.768777     115.252163  88.603262
2013-07-01        0.677020      81.824781  55.396987
2013-08-01        0.673639      72.489988  48.832110
2013-09-01        0.783291     125.034417  97.938296
2013-10-01        0.779694     118.724648  92.568902
2013-11-01        0.771430     113.322446  87.420366
2013-12-01        0.680166     100.950857  68.663388
2014-01-01        0.573320     102.881633  58.984090
```

And this is the very basic fitting I'm trying to run for the very beginning.

```
model = VAR(df)
results = model.fit(2)
results.forecast(df.values[-2:], 5)
results.summary()
```

I'm assuming I need to set some kind of a frequency attribute to the dataframe. I've tried doing a brute df.asfreq('M') but it simply messes up my data.

Comment: can you try `df.index.freq='M'`? and this only works when there's no missing value of a consecutive time series. this is the detail about pandas timeseries. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Comment: I think this is a good direction and I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something trivial. But this thing doesn't work, I've tried peeling off the day '%d' from the datetime so maybe this makes the error go away but no.

I came up with the 'freq' attribute put along the line, and it made the code proceed to another error.

model = VAR(df, freq='M')

Gives:

ValueError: The given frequency argument could not be matched to the given index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the model you are using, however most likely it's either caused by the missing values in the time series or by the non matched `freq` (`freq` for the month beginning is `MS`).

So as I think, you can create a new time series with [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), then [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the dataframe with the created time series.

if the input dataframe is:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
            0  1
2018-01-01  2  1
2018-03-01  0  0
```

we can then create a new time series:

```
In [12]: index = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='MS')

In [13]: index
Out[13]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

then reindex the dataframe

```
In [14]: df.reindex(index)
Out[14]:
            0    1
2018-01-01  2.0  1.0
2018-02-01  NaN  NaN
2018-03-01  0.0  0.0
```

and additionally we can fill the `Nan` values in the dataframe with some appropriate values to meet the model training.

Comment: To everyone encountering the same error: high probability that there is something wrong with the datetime. Something missing or not continuous. There were no NaNs, the datetime index was mixed up in the middle with a couple of dates so it was not continous. I've decided on my own to repopulate the date just to be sure that days and months are on their respective spots (the original .csv file had it all mixed up) but your solution is much more elegant, although it needs a sort to work (not the final date on .max otherwise). So, thank you, that .min/.max way is something I'm running with.